# Overwrite Expiration date in Portal JWT responses

Tags: api, jwt, portal

I'm having a security problem with my portal users. When they login into the portal from a VisualForce page using the `Site.login()` we are receiving in the browser 48 JWTs without an expiration date.

Here is an example of one:

```
{
   "nonce": "nsNMVkLo6zbj6HoZhCyPO4PKKTShpm9UbzDx8ZTP34I\u003d",
   "typ": "JWT",
   "alg": "HS256",
   "kid": "{\"t\":\"00D3D00000031kI\",\"v\":\"02G61000000LaD6\",\"a\":\"vfremotingsigningkey\",\"u\":\"0053D000004k31K\"}",
"crit": [
    "iat"
],
   "iat": 1674587001589,
   "exp": 0
}
```

**Is there a way in the Visualforce controller to change the response from the server to add the expiration in the JWTs?**

Comment: Welcome to SFSE! Please take a moment to read [How to Ask](https://salesforce.stackexchange.com/questions/how-to-ask) and take the [tour](https://salesforce.stackexchange.com/tour).  Including a [Minimal, Reproducible Example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example) would be helpful.

Comment: Can you include the code you use so that we can try to recreate this?